# Limiting Powershell Get-ChildItem by File Creation Date Range

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I use a Powershell command to generate a CSV report of certain file types. My goal is to find out how many were added during a particular date range. Right now, the script finds everything and I sort by date to find my number. I'd like to modify the command to only return objects within a creation date rage, i.e. if this file was created between 1 March 2013 and 31 March 2013. There's probably a way to limit the command by a date range, likely using Select-Object, I just can't figure it out.

```
Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.tif*","*.jp2","*.pdf") | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={$_.Length/1Kb}}, @{Name="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days)}} | Export-Csv 'PATH\scans.csv'
```

Comment: For the record, I'm not familiar with Powershell and did not know what to search for. The command I was using was grabbed from elsewhere online. I did search Google to find this answer and was not able to; that's where my thought about using Select-Object came from. I reject and resent your statements, this is supposed to be a help forum; but, I appreciate your help.

Comment: +1 because Nathan *did* make an effort. There's a difference between someone who's unfamiliar with a technology (and may not know even what to search for) and someone making no effort. [Clarifying my earlier comment--"+1" indicates I upvoted your question to counteract the downvotes] :-)

Comment: I guess I just expect more. A simple search for "powershell get files creation date" on google would give him everything except `-and` on the first hit, and you don't need powershell knowledge to come up with that search phrase =)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` and test the `$_.CreationTime`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.tif*","*.jp2","*.pdf") | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge "03/01/2013" -and $_.CreationTime -le "03/31/2013" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Where-Object`, like:

```
Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.tif*","*.jp2","*.pdf") | 
Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt "03/01/2013" -and $_.CreationTime -lt "03/31/2013" }
Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={$_.Length/1Kb}}, @{Name="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days)}} | 
Export-Csv 'PATH\scans.csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it...

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\ -recurse -include @("*.txt*","*.pdf") |
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt "01/01/2013" -and $_.CreationTime -lt "12/02/2014"} | 
Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={$_.Length/1Kb}}, @{Name="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days)}} | 
Export-Csv C:\search_TXT-and-PDF_files_01012013-to-12022014_sort.txt
```

Comment: please use block quote by appending 4 spaces to `Get-ChildItem`