# Parsing several thousand log files

Tags: powershell, performance, parsing, logging

I currently have to parse around 35000 to 50000 log files to extract lines of interest.
Due to limitations and policies I have to do it in Powershell without any external libraries.

Size of logs is between between 100 kB and 1000 kB.

I write the results into a single file which has about 5 million to 7 million lines at the end.

The performance is gruesome... it takes around 1 hour and 15 minutes to parse 50000 logs and write the results into the output file.

I only know that this is bad for performance:

```ps
if (($result[1..8] -join "").Trim() -ne "") {
```

As well as having a nested loop with a complexity of O(V*E) *correct me if I'm wrong*

```ps
foreach ($file in $fileList) {
   ...
   while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
   ...
```

The `$search` variable hold the string "Custom Log Entry: "

As per your request here is an example of the log files content:

> Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info: A String with some Info:
> mail.address@domain.com
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info: Second
> string with some info
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info: XZY 000000000
> some information about the current line
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021
> Info: XZY 000000000 some action has happened: action
>  Sat Oct  2
> 00:20:12 2021 Info: XZY 000000000 something was used: used object
> Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info: XZY 000000000 some information about
> the current line
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info: XZY 000000000 some
> information about the current line
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021 Info:
> XZY 000000000 Some Data: verdict negative
>  Sat Oct  2 00:20:12 2021
> Info: XZY 000000000 Custom Log Entry: IMPORTANT LINE
>  Sat Oct  2
> 00:20:12 2021 Info: XZY 000000000 some information
>  Sat Oct  2
> 00:20:12 2021 Custom Log Entry: IMPORTANT LINE

I looked at `foreach -parallel (...)` but the limitations of Workflows are just terrible...

Maybe just open each file, write it to a MemoryStream and then process all (RAM isn't an issue)?

Can you guys give me any advice on how to speed this up?

Here's a more thorough look at the code:

```ps
try {
    # Output stream in which we write.
    $outStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream( `
        "C:\Users\anon\outfile.csv", `
        [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, `
        [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, `
        [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    # Writer object which is used to write to stream.
    $outWrite = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outStream)
    # Iterate through files.
    foreach ($file in $fileList) {       

        try {
            # Create reader stream for log.
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)    
            # Length of time stamp
            $fileNameDateLen = fileNameDateFormat.Length 
            $fileNameDate = $file.Substring($file.Length - 2 - $fileNameDateLen, $fileNameDateLen)
            # Convert to usable DateTime object.
            $fileNameDateConverted = ([System.DateTime]::ParseExact(`
                $fileNameDate, `
                $fileNameDateFormat, `
                [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture))
            # Change format of extracted file name date.
            $fileNameDateConverted = $fileNameDateConverted.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")                        
            # StringBuilder for storing row values.
            $rowBuffer = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
            # Iterate through files.
            while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
                # Validate line.
                if ($line -Match $search) {       
                    # Calc position of relevant data.
                    $pos = $line.IndexOf($search) + $searchLength
                    # Actual length of relevant data.
                    $relLength = $line.Length - $pos
                    # Extract relevant data.
                    $result = $line.Substring($pos, $relLength).Trim().Split(';')      
                    # Check if line is empty.
                    if (($result[1..8] -join "").Trim() -ne "") {
                        # Get timestamp from line.
                        #$timeValue = $timeRegex.Match($line).Value
                        $timeValue = $line.Substring(12, 8)
                        # Combine date from file name with time.
                        $dateString = "$fileNameDateConverted $timeValue"
                        # Format timestamp.
                        $timeStamp = Get-Date $dateString -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                        # Format last result.
                        $result[8] = $result[8] -Replace "^""|""$"
                        # Create CSV row.
                        [void] $rowBuffer.AppendLine("$timeStamp;$($result[1]);$($result[2]);" `
                            + "$($result[3]);$($result[4]);$($result[5]);" `
                            + "$($result[6]);$($result[7]);$($result[8])")          
                    }
                }
            }
            # Write results to file.
            $outWrite.Write($rowBuffer.ToString())
            # Clear buffer.
            [void] $rowBuffer.Clear()
            # Close input.
            [void] $reader.Close()
            # Free input memory.
            [void] $reader.Dispose()
        }   
        catch {
            if ($rowBuffer -ne $null) {
                [void] $rowBuffer.Clear()
            }
            if ($reader -ne $null) {
                [void] $reader.Close()
                [void] $reader.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    $sp.Stop()
    Write-Host "Finished after $($sp.Elapsed)"
} 
catch {
    if ($outWrite -ne $null) { 
        [void] $outWrite.Dispose()
    }
    if ($outStream -ne $null) {
        [void] $outStream.Dispose()
    }
}
finally {
    # Close and free output.
    [void] $outWrite.Close()
    [void] $outStream.Close()
    [void] $outWrite.Dispose()
    [void] $outStream.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: While you may very well get some excellent advice here on StackOverflow, you might want to consider posting questions like this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. That said, I'll go take a look at what you have and see if I spot anything. There's a few users here that are amazing at that kind of thing, but I may come across something that could help.

Comment: What is stored in `$search` and what does the input look like?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thank you I didn't now about the code review domain :)

Comment: You could try pre-compiling your regex - something like ```$myRegex = [Regex]::new($search, "Compiled, IgnoreCase, CultureInvariant")``` and then ```$match = $myRegex.Match($line); if( $match.Success ) { ... }```. The ```$match``` object gives you the start, length and string that matches so you can maybe get to ```$result``` quicker (```$result = $match.Value.Trim().Split(";")```. You'd need to measure performance to see if it actually helps though...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen $search = "Custom Log Entry: " and the lines that I want look like this "Sat Oct  2 00:08:26 2021 Some: Text I don't care about Custom Log Entry: data;data;data;data;data" and the other log lines only share the date time value at the beginning

Comment: @Max Please add a few sample entries [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69487053/edit) (scrubbed of anything sensitive if necessary)

Comment: @mclayton I will do a performance test on that, thank you! Does the -match operator actually use regex?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The other lines only share the time stamp that has a fixed length everything else is completely different and I only look for lines that contain the string "Custom Log Entry: ". I can provide a few examples tomorrow but as I said the only qualifying portion is the "Custom Log Entry: " string which position may vary.

Comment: It does use regex under the covers, but I've got no idea whether it optimises repeated calls that use same pattern, or blindly re-parses your pattern every time. If you create your own regex object you *know* it's pre-compiled, and you get all the positional properties of the ```System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match``` object as well.

Comment: @mclayton: PowerShell [performs its own regex caching](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e98a8c8601b8f15f479e894323beafb9f6a2300c/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/lang/parserutils.cs#L1208), up to 1000 regexes per distinct set of regex options. [.NET itself performs caching too](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions), but only for regexes passed to _static_ method calls. Such caching uses "high-level  codes" as the compilation target, whereas only _explicit_ compilation yields MSIL code that can be JITted.

Comment: Your biggest perf gains will be to use multi-threading.  Using RunSpaceFactories, move everything inside your loop in a script block.  Create the script block so it takes the filepath as an argument.  Create a runspace using your script block and pass in the filenames and add them all into your runspacefactory. 

Because each runspace will run into locking issues writing to a single output file, you can have each thread write to it's own log file and then after they're all done processing, you can synchronously consolidate all of the output files.

Comment: The fact that you even have a selfmade CSV solution  (rather than using [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)) suggest that you have an unfounded prejudiced look on the PowerShell performance. If you state the PowerShell performance as gruesome you should at least try to use **native PowerShell** commands as the `Switch -File` and cmdlets  as `Select-String` and the pipeline. Anyways, to be able adequately answer you and test/show you anything better, we need a [mcve] including the `$search` contents and input examples.

Comment: @Max Still waiting for you to post an actual log sample...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added a few log lines to the original question. Issue is mostly resolved after implementing multi-threading as thepip3r suggested

Answer (score 0):

I followed [thepip3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158069/thepip3r) recommendation and went Multi-Threading which was by far the most relevant thing to do.

I didn't write the parse results into individual files as memory just isn't an issue for me in this case. All of my return values are stored in a ConcurrentBag which is a thread-safe collection.
For everyone with limited memory you might want to use an atomic write like this (it will slow you down a bit):

```ps
    # Atomic write stream object for thread-safe file append.
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream( `
        $destFile, `
        [System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate, `
        [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::AppendData, `
        [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, `
        0x2000, 
        [System.IO.FileOptions]::None)

    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
    # Enable AutoFlush or FileStream will keep on buffering.
    $writer.AutoFlush = $true
    # Get thread results and dispose them.
    foreach ($thread in $parserThreads) {        
        $writer.WriteLine(($thread.Thread.EndInvoke($thread.Status) | Out-String))
        $thread.Thread.Dispose()
    }
    $parserThreads = $null
```

After utilizing multithreading the time went down from 70-83 minutes to 20-33 minutes (depending on how many large(r) input files were loaded.

Not using Export-CSV or pipes is simply quicker.
Pipes are rather slow and I think they are unnecessary (most of the time). Using things like ConvertTo-Csv or Select-String or whatever just adds overhead that I don't want nor need for a simple task like this. Collecting the input files has been done with pipes in the beginning similar like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884173/limiting-powershell-get-childitem-by-file-creation-date-range). The two nested foreach loops with a single IF condition together are about 200 times faster then the piped version (50 seconds for pipe version and <250ms for nested-loops)... so yes, I do have prejudice against PowerShells performance and pipes.

Thank you all for your comments, help, recommendations.

Here is the result code:

```ps
Clear

try {
    
    $ParseLog = {

        Param (
            # File to parse
            [string]$targetFile,
            # Search string
            [string]$searchValue
        )

        try {
            # Length of search string. 
            $svLength = $searchValue.Length            
            # Date time format found within file name.
            $fileNameDateFormat = "yyyyMMddTHHmmss"
            # Init reader object.
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($targetFile)    
            # Get date from file name.
            $fileNameTimeLen = $fileNameDateFormat.Length
            # Extract the date time value from the file name. 
            $fileNameTime = $targetFile.Substring($targetFile.Length - 2 - $fileNameTimeLen, $fileNameTimeLen)
            # Convert to usable DateTime object.
            $fileDateConverted = ([System.DateTime]::ParseExact(`
                $fileNameTime, `
                $fileNameDateFormat, `
                [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture))
            # Change format of extracted file name date.
            $fileDateConverted = $fileDateConverted.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            # StringBuilder for storing row values.
            $rowBuffer = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
            # Iterate through files.
            while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
                # Validate line.
                if ($line -Match $searchValue) {       
                    # Calc position of relevant data.
                    $pos = $line.IndexOf($searchValue) + $svLength
                    # Actual length of relevant data.
                    $relLength = $line.Length - $pos
                    # Extract relevant data.
                    $result = $line.Substring($pos, $relLength).Trim().Split(';')  
                    # Check if line is empty.
                    if (($result[1..8] -join "").Trim() -ne "") {
                        # Get timestamp from line (position and length is fixed).
                        $timeValue = $line.Substring(12, 8)
                        # Combine date from file name with time.
                        $dateString = "$fileDateConverted $timeValue"
                        # Format timestamp.
                        $timeStamp = Get-Date $dateString -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                        # Format last result.
                        $result[8] = $result[8] -Replace "^""|""$" -Replace "\\xc3\\xbc", "ue"
                        # Create CSV row.
                        [void] $rowBuffer.AppendLine("$timeStamp;$($result[1]);$($result[2]);" `
                            + "$($result[3]);$($result[4]);$($result[5]);" `
                            + "$($result[6]);$($result[7]);$($result[8])")          
                    }
                }
            }
            # Close input.
            [void] $reader.Close()
            # Free input memory.
            [void] $reader.Dispose()
            # Return the parser result.
            return $rowBuffer.ToString()
        }   
        catch {
            # Free memory
            if ($rowBuffer -ne $null) {
                [void] $rowBuffer.Clear()
            }
            # Free StreamReader memory.
            if ($reader -ne $null) {
                [void] $reader.Close()
                [void] $reader.Dispose()
            }
            # Return error for debugging.
            #return $error[0].Exception()
        }
    }

    # StopWatch object to measure performance.
    $sp = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    # Root path of log directories
    $basePath = "\\some\network\path"
    # Test directories
    $directories = @("dir0", "dir1")
    # Text we need to look for within the the logs files.
    $search = "Custom Log Entry: "
    # Cache length of search as we need it quite often.
    $searchLength = $search.Length
    # Test start date
    $Start = Get-Date -Date "01.07.2021" 
    # Test end date
    $End = Get-Date -Date "11.10.2021"
    # List object storing file paths.
    $fileList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
    # List object storing directory paths. 
    $dirList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]

    # Collect all directories and sub-directories.
    foreach ($dir in $directories) {    
        # Combine directories
        $path = "$basePath\$dir\subdir"
        # Get directory info.
        $dirInfo = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($path) 
        # iterate through sub-directories.
        foreach ($subDir in $dirInfo.GetDirectories()) {
            # Cache creation time.
            $ct = $subDir.CreationTime.Date
            # Check if folder meets requirements.
            if ($ct -ge $Start.Date -and $ct -le $End.Date) {
                $dirList.Add($subDir.FullName)
            }        
        }
    }
    $sp.Stop()
    Write-Host "Received all directories after: $($sp.Elapsed)"

    $sp.Restart()
    # Temp array for files.
    $files = @()
    # Iterate through files in folder list.
    foreach ($dir in $dirList) {
        # Get directory info.
        $dirInfo = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo($dir)
        # Get all log files.
        $files = $dirInfo.GetFiles("*.log", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
        # Iterate through files.
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            # Cache last write time.
            $lwt = $file.LastWriteTime
            # Check if file is applicable.
            if ($lwt -ge $Start.Date -and $lwt -le $End.Date) {
                $fileList.Add($file.FullName)
            }
        }    
    }
    $sp.Stop()
    Write-Host "Received all files after: $($sp.Elapsed)"

    # CSV header string.
    $header = "h0;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;h7;h8"
    
    # Use a threadsafe collection object to store thread results. 
    $threadSafeBuffer = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]]::new()
    # Create new thread pool.
    $parserThreadPool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, [int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
    # Set multithreaded apartment state.
    $parserThreadPool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
    $parserThreadPool.Open()
    $parserThreads = @()

    $sp.Restart()

    # Iterate through files.
    foreach ($file in $fileList) {     
        # Create thread for file.
        $parserThread = [PowerShell]::Create()
        # Load parser script.
        [void] $parserThread.AddScript($ParseLog)
        # Pass parameters.
        [void] $parserThread.AddArgument($file) 
        [void] $parserThread.AddArgument($search) 
        # Add to thread pool
        $parserThread.RunspacePool = $parserThreadPool
        # Thread callback
        $parserThreads += [PSCustomObject]@{ `
            Thread = $parserThread; `
            Status = $parserThread.BeginInvoke() `
        }                
    }

    # Wait for threads to finish.
    while ($parserThreads.Status.IsCompleted -notcontains $true) {}
    # Get thread results and dispose them.
    foreach ($thread in $parserThreads) {                
        [void] $threadSafeBuffer.TryAdd($thread.Thread.EndInvoke($thread.Status))
        $thread.Thread.Dispose()
    }
    $sp.Stop()
    Write-Host "Finished parsing after: $($sp.Elapsed)"

    $sp.Restart()
    # Create stream and writer for output.
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream( `
        "c:\users\anon\documents\parser_result\result.csv", `
        [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, `
        [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write, `
        [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
    
    # Write results into file.         
    foreach ($item in $threadSafeBuffer) {
        $writer.WriteLine($item)
    }

    # Free memory.
    $threadSafeBuffer = $null
    $writer.Close()
    $writer.Dispose()
    $stream.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()
    $parserThreadPool.Close()
    $parserThreadPool.Dispose()

    $sp.Stop()
    Write-Host "Finished writing parser results after $($sp.Elapsed)"
} 
catch {

    $threadSafeBuffer = $null

    if ($parserThreadPool -ne $null) {
        $parserThreadPool.Close() 
        $parserThreadPool.Dispose() 
    }

    if ($writer -ne $null) {
        $writer.Close()
        $writer.Dispose()
    }   
    
    if ($stream -ne $null) {     
        $stream.Close()
        $stream.Dispose()
    }
}
```